# Disable ordering of post with drag and drop

Tags: php, wordpress

I don't want to allow order the post with drag and drop to move your position on the page in wordpress admin.

Comment: please describe your question with plugin name.

Comment: I am not using any plugin, i am asking about ordering of wordpress's post and pages.@ShitalMarakana

Comment: please try this plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/post-types-order/

Comment: Thanx @ShitalMarakana it works. The plugin is already there but the solution is i have to uncheck **Archive Drag&Drop** option in setting.

Comment: good :) please marked as solved

Comment: how can i mark comment ?

Comment: You simply need to mark an below answer as correct (the green check image).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use "post-types-order" plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/post-types-order/